# Trigger "Like" function on the static image button given by client

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Generally I am developing a fanpage which require users to "Like" before enter the content. I had been given a static image with a like button on the image which is silly I guess > <. I know how to put a div on that particular position and triggering a function call. However I don't know the way of calling "Like" function on it.

Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Eric.

Comment: I'm guessing you've been asked to do this by your client ("I've been given..."). Your client needs to think about what he's asking you to do; it's very, very bad to require an action before allowing access to a page, IMO. Also, you could wrap the image in a `<a>` tag, although we could use more info.

Comment: what do you mean in <a> tag mind to give example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
However I don't know the way of calling "Like"
```

what do you mean ? the function/procedure of the "like" if that's the case you just have to  add it on the database the refresh the part of it the counter label and thats all.. hope this will help.

Comment: seen those fanpage that require the "Like" before entering? If I do it in database directly, the like button on the top will be still exist which is not making sense.

Comment: no you can include it on your refreshing part check if it does exist then hide the like button

Answer (score 0):

You can't *mimic* the Like functionality, you need to use the [Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or encourage the user (in your image) to click on the like button on top of the page.

The second approach is widely used by major brands like [Coca-Coca](http://www.facebook.com/cocacola) and [Red Bull](http://www.facebook.com/redbull) for example.

Comment: I seen an apps that able to make it that way. But they were somehow using "Like" generated code to triger the "Like" on fanpage.

Comment: You can "Like" Facebook posts,links and comments programmatically but not pages.